# Rbind isn't working in R

Tags: r, data-analysis

I am new to R programming language and when I tried the rbind command I am getting an error

```
a=c(2,3,5,8,13)
b=c("a","b","c","d","e")
c$d=c(11111111,2222222,44333333,4444444444,5555555)
```

And now when I execute

```
c
a b          d
1  2 a   11111111
2  3 b    2222222
3  5 c   44333333
4  8 d 4444444444
5 13 e    5555555
```

this is the output 
When i tried rbind function i am getting an error like mentioned below

```
a1=c(1,2,3,4,5)
b1=c("a","b","c","d","e")
c1=c(22222,111111,333333,444444,555555)
d1=data.frame(a1,b1,c1)
total=rbind(c,d1)
```

> **Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) :    names do not match previous names**

Comment: with `rbind` you need to have the same column names

Comment: The names between the variables in the `data.frames` must be the same.

Comment: Since `c` is the name of a built-in function, it is ill-advised to try to use it as the name of a variable.

Comment: The error message comes from `rbind.data.frame` i.e. check the `match.names<-`

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestions guys its working now.